# Xcode how to add an external project

Tags: xcode, workspace, build-dependencies

I need to add an external project to my Xcode project, the reason for this is I need to add a Target Dependency on that external projects static library.

I can't seem to add it in the way I need, I would like it like this:

[image]

However, when I add another project to my actual Xcode project I get the following which doesn't let me explore that project from my one and so I can't add the dependency I need.

[image]

Note that these screenshots are from two different projects, and in the one which is showing me what I want to reproduce in my own project, dragging in multiple projects works as expected.

Maybe I have some settings set up wrong in my project ? All I've done is take a template detail-master application from Xcode.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You did it right. The problem is that Xcode cannot have the same project opened twice.

Close `Serenity.xcodeproj` before reopening your parent project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, it's called a workspace.

In your example:

- Open both of your projects
- Drag the Serenity project into the Dependant project

I think what you are doing wrong is dragging the Xcodeproj, try opening that project and dragging the project block instead (see pic)

[image]

Comment: Hello, I tried that, no luck, but @gcamp had the right answer. Thanks for your help